# DTUTIL to package store

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am trying to deploy a package to a project in my SSIS catalog and am using the following command:

```
dtutil /FILE C:\Changes\ReceivedEDI.dtsx /DestS MARSQL12 /COPY DTS;TradingPartners\TradingPartner\ReceivedEDI
```

Where the TradingPartners is the folder name, the TradingPartner is the project name and the ReceivedEDI is the package name.

I am getting an error of:

```
Error (0x800706BA) while checking for the existence of package "TradingPartners\
TradingPartner\ReceivedEDI" in the SSIS package store.
Error (0x800706BA) saving package "TradingPartners\TradingPartner\ReceivedEDI" t
o the SSIS package store.
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this may have your answer: http://dbbulletin.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/dtutil-named-instance-and-package-import/

Comment: That article explains how to deploy to MSDB but not the SSISDB catalog for an existing project.

Comment: OK I got a good answer on SQLServerCentral: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1577722-2799-1.aspx